# How to generate series of date based on yyyymm in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

We will pass month information in yyyyMM format.From that given input how i will get FirstDate to LastDate of that month?

Input:-202005

OutPut Should be:-

2020-05-01,
2020-05-02,
.....
2020-05-31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()` for that:

```
select g.dt::date
from generate_series(to_date('202005', 'yyyymm'), 
                     to_date('202005', 'yyyymm') + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day',
                     interval '1 day') as g(dt);
```